# Is there a way for changing where a MPI process is running?

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing

I have several MPI processes running in a node. Some of them are bound to the same thread and its efficiency is notably reduced. Can I move a process to other free threads while it's running?

Comment: you can use `taskset`

Comment: By free threads do you mean free cores?

Comment: Yes. `taskset` worked for me @GillesGouaillardet , you can use it as an answer